# Preventing click jacking on MERN App using X-Frame-Options or helmet

Tags: node.js, reactjs, x-frame-options, clickjacking, helmet.js

I am trying to create web application using React and Node that is secure from Click jacking, I have understood that i need to either set the X-Frame-Options to deny manually or use helmet to prevent other sites loading my web app using iframes. I have set the below config in my index.js of server

```
const helmet = require("helmet")
app.use(helmet())
```

When i try to call a get Login API from inside an iframe of a decoy website(basic html page), i am getting a status 200 response and the web app is loaded into the iframe. But i believe the web app should fail to load in the iframe of decoy site. My Login component looks something like this.

```
function Login(){
    useEffect(()=>{
        Axios.get(`http://localhost:8888/isLoggedIn`, {
            headers:{
                "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token")
            }
        }).then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
            if(response.data.loggedin){
                navigate("/")
            }
        })
    }
```

As mentioned in the problem, I am getting 200 for isLoggedIn call.
When i checked the api call from the decoy site network tab, I see the isLoggedIn call has origin set to "http://localhost:3000", which is actual domain of react app.
Below is the decoy site html code.

```
<body>
    <div id="decoy_website">
        Decoy Web Site for Secure Login  Page
    </div>
    <iframe id="target_website" src="http://localhost:3000/login">
    </iframe>
</body>
```

Please let me know if i am not using the helmet the correct way, or the additional steps that need to be done to prevent my site from click jacking.

Answer (score 1):

Well, You can prevent **clickjacking** attack by setting the **X-Frame-Options** to **DENY** or **SAMEORIGIN**, but if you want to use **helmet** in efficient way you can add the following code to the JavaScript file you use to start your web app or index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet');

const app = express();

// setting the X-Frame-Options header to SAMEORIGIN
app.use(helmet.frameguard({ action: 'sameorigin' })); // OR you can set it to DENY
```

this is the right way of using **helmet** for setting **X-Frame-Options**

but loading a login page in an iframe tag can cause **more vulnerabilities** than clickjacking. I don't suggest it in real projects.